# Python OOP - Calling a recursive function inside a class

Tags: python, oop, recursion, python-class

I was trying to solve the well known coding problem - find the number of islands in this grid. It is used in various job interviews and leetcode.

For my take on it, I thought I'd try and come up with an OOP style using classes.

I came across the issue of a recursive function inside a class with a constructor.

I just passed in the current parameters but it just looks messy to me...

```
def depthFirstSearch(self, x , y , grid):

 if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= row or y >= col or grid [ x ] [ y ] == 0 :
   return

 grid [ x ] [ y ] = 0

 # Recursive calls
 sol = Solution(row, col, grid)   # Messy? Passing in same vales as in constructor.
 sol.depthFirstSearch( x + 1 , y , grid )       
 sol.depthFirstSearch( x - 1 , y , grid )
 sol.depthFirstSearch( x , y + 1 , grid )
 sol.depthFirstSearch( x , y - 1 , grid )
 return
```

These values are being passed into the class by the constructor:

```
# constructor
  def __init__(self, row, col, grid):
    self.row = row
    self.col = col
    self.grid = grid
```

Is that how I should be accessing them?

My full code:

```
class Solution :

  # constructor
  def __init__(self, row, col, grid):
    self.row = row
    self.col = col
    self.grid = grid

  # check x and y co-ords are not negative values or larger than the grid row/column length
  # check the grid co-ord isn't already 0.
  def depthFirstSearch(self, x , y , grid):

     if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= row or y >= col or grid [ x ] [ y ] == 0 :
       return              # break the loop, return none.

     # Mark cell as 0
     # we sink the islands once counted, to avoid counting them again
     grid [ x ] [ y ] = 0

     # Recursive calls
     # Search the surrounding cells
     sol = Solution(row, col, grid)           # Messy? Passing in same vales as in constructor.
     sol.depthFirstSearch( x + 1 , y , grid )       
     sol.depthFirstSearch( x - 1 , y , grid )
     sol.depthFirstSearch( x , y + 1 , grid )
     sol.depthFirstSearch( x , y - 1 , grid )
     return


 def Islands (self) :

    islands = 0

    # check there's data in the grid
    if not grid : return 0

    # Traverse grid
    for x in range ( 0 , row ) :
     for y in range ( 0 , col ) :
       # when we find an island "1" search around it
       if grid [ x ] [ y ] == 1 :
         Solution(row, col, grid).depthFirstSearch( x , y , grid )
         islands += 1        # Increase island count

   return islands


if __name__ == '__main__':
  grid = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1 ], [0, 1, 0]]
  row = len ( grid )
  col = len ( grid [ 0 ] )

  s = Solution(row, col, grid)
  ans = s.Islands()

print('Number of Islands :  {0}'.format(ans))
```

FYI, the 1s are islands so there is 3 of them here.
0s are the sea.

```
[1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0], 
[1, 0, 1], 
[0, 1, 0]
```

How are you supposed to have a function inside a class with a constructor call itself in python?

Comment: you dont need to intialise same class to call some function, you can call the function or do recursion with `self` . so remoeve `sol = Solution(row, col, grid)` and change `  sol.depthFirstSearch( x + 1 , y , grid )` to `self.depthFirstSearch( x + 1 , y , grid )` also since grid is saved one time no need to keep passing it, just use self.grid to access it

Comment: It currently works, but you suspect it not to follow best practices (with good reasons...). I really think that you could post it instead on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get good advices on how to improve your code.

Comment: I wouldn't use OOP here. OOP just gets in the way when you have a stateless function. None of the data to solve the problem really needs to outlive a function scoping. Leetcode always uses OOP boilerplate in Python and I suspect it just confuses people into thinking OOP is somehow magically better practice across the board. Also, allocating and garbage collecting objects is slow, on top of recursion which is already slow/poor practice in Python. As an aside, please use `snake_case` not `camelCase` in Python and always indent 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't even know codereview.stackexchange.com existed! I appreciate all the advice